# Gravatar Javascript Multiple Emails

Tags: php, javascript, md5, gravatar

Ref: [Loading gravatar using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705344/loading-gravatar-using-jquery)

I am using the above method to generate the gravatar on a page however I have multiple emails on the page and the code is only generating one MD5 and therefore only one gravatar my JS is:

```
var email = $('#email').val();
var digestString = Crypto.MD5(email);
$('#md5').val(digestString);
var gravatar = $('<img>').attr({src: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + digestString});
$('.gravatar').append(gravatar);
```

I am using Crypto MD5 http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ and that is loaded in the header the emails are held in a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $message['contact_email'];?>">
```

These are printing out ok for each user.

Any help would be great

EDIT *****

HTML OUTPUT Working:

```
<div class="message-author">
<span class="gravatar" style="height: 24px;">
      <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/82c9a9c254f35a912d8fefc248c30fd8"></span>
      <input type="hidden" id="md5" value="82c9a9c254f35a912d8fefc248c30fd8">
      <input type="hidden" class="email" value="themailname@thecompany.com">
</div>
```

HTML OUTPUT not Working:

```
<div class="message-author">
<span class="gravatar" style="height: 24px;">
      <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/82c9a9c254f35a912d8fefc248c30fd8"></span>
      <input type="hidden" id="md5" value="">
      <input type="hidden" class="email" value="themailname@thecompany.com">
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php foreach ($messages['page'] as $message): ?>
    <li class="message">
        <div class="message-body"><?php echo $message['message']; ?></div>
        <div class="message-author">
            <span class="gravatar" style="height: 24px;"></span>
            <input type="hidden" class="md5" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="email" value="<?php echo $message['contact_email'];?>">
            <?php echo $message['contact_person'];?> - 
            <?php echo date("m M - g:i a", $message['created']); ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can we seen the HTML to see how the `.gravatar` element is positioned relative to each `<input />` holding the email? If you've got PHP available, why aren't you doing this in PHP? It also *seems* that you're using the same ID for multiple elements on the same page... this is invalid. ID's must be unique... try using a class instead.

Comment: @Matt added as requested want to use javascript really if possible thanks for your help the far

Comment: why are you not generating all the md5 hashes and images and stuff by php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('input.email').each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var md5 = Crypto.MD5(this.value);

    self.siblings('.md5').val(md5);
    self.siblings('.gravatar').append($('<img />').prop('src', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + md5));
});
```

You need to introduce a loop (via [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each)) to consult each `email` element individually; otherwise, as you realised, only the first is looked at (as *getters* such as `val()` will only return the value of the *first* matched element.

However, as I hinted at [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941177/gravatar-javascript-multiple-emails#comment12692313_9941177), this should *really* be a job for PHP; it's also a potentially privacy issue sending users emails in your HTML.